# while loop not working in shell

Tags: shell, sh

Can anyone help me with the below. I do not understand what is wrong, Not getting any output. My requirement is to read a file and check if it's not empty and to print the content line by line.

```
   #!/bin/ksh
   echo " enter file name "
   read $file
   if [ -f "$file" ] && [ -s "$file" ]
    then 
   echo " file does not exist, or is empty "
      else
   while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$file" ]];do
      echo "$line"
   done
   fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read $file` should be `read file`

Your comparison logic is backwards. 
The comparison `if [ -f "$file" ] && [ -s "$file" ]` is 'if the file is a regular file and not empty go into error case'. You want 'if the file is not regular or the file is empty go into error case' `if [ -f "$file" ] -eq 0 || [ -s "$file" ] -eq 0`.

[Per ksh file read](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ksh-read-file/) should be

```
 while IFS='' read -r line 
   do
      echo "$line"
   done < "$file"
```

[Further Reading On ksh redirection](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-io-redirections.htm)